# Trying to get property of non-object Zend Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

I'm moving a site from development to production and suddenly this error keeps popping up:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/httpdocs/application/Bootstrap.php on line 16
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/httpdocs/application/Bootstrap.php on line 17
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/httpdocs/application/Bootstrap.php on line 18
```

The code at that point writes:

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $param = array( "template_dir"  => $config->smarty->template_dir,
                    "compile_dir"   => $config->smarty->compile_dir,
                    "config_dir"    => $config->smarty->config_dir,
                    "cache_dir"     => $config->smarty->cache_dir
                    );

    $view = new Zend_View_Smarty(null, $param);
```

So the $config seems to be a non object, lets var_dump that:

```
object(Zend_Config_Ini)#43 (11) { ... }
```

Seems like an object to me, thought maybe the config file cant be read. But I can fopen, fread it and the values are listed in the var_dump.

The only difference between my normal sites and this one; its running on a subdomain. I can't figure out what that has to do with Zend_Config_Ini, especially when the config file can be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time further...I found out that an line in the ini file wasnt properly closed with a quote:

```
site.basedir        = "/
```

shoulda be:

```
site.basedir        = "/"
```

those monday mornings :-)